# How to combine MIN and MAX inside a WHERE condition

Tags: sql, sybase

I have this query which requires to find a MAX value given certain description

```
select * from SCA_FXDFWD_REP S
where S.M_TRADE_NUM in  (SELECT MAX(S_AUX.M_TRADE_NUM)
                         FROM SCA_FXDFWD_REP S_AUX
                         WHERE S_AUX.M_ORIGIN_ID= S.M_ORIGIN_ID
                         AND S_AUX.M_SCA_DESC= 'ALTA'
                         GROUP BY  S_AUX.M_SCA_ORIG, S_AUX.M_TRADE_DAT)
```

And that works fine, but now I need to add another condition which requires to find de MIN for another similar condition like this:

```
SELECT * FROM SCA_FXDFWD_REP S
WHERE M_TRADE_NUM IN ((SELECT MIN(M_TRADE_NUM) FROM SCA_FXDFWD_REP S_AUX 
where S_AUX.M_ORIGIN_ID = S.M_ORIGIN_ID
AND S_AUX.M_SCA_DESC= 'UTILIZACION'))
```

I've tried `AND`, `OR`, `UNION`, and all kind of combinations in my knowledge to combine both conditions and get `MAX` when `DESC='ALTA'` and `MIN` when `DESC='UTILIZACION'` with no luck, I usually get an error where the prefix S won't match, etc.

Can anybody help on what would be the best way to combine this two condition and get only both MIN and MAX at the same time

Thanks,

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: @Joan . . . Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: I guess union all must solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `or` in where condition

```
select * from SCA_FXDFWD_REP S
where S.M_TRADE_NUM =  (SELECT MAX(S_AUX.M_TRADE_NUM)
                         FROM SCA_FXDFWD_REP S_AUX
                         WHERE S_AUX.M_ORIGIN_ID= S.M_ORIGIN_ID
                         AND S_AUX.M_SCA_DESC= 'ALTA'
                         GROUP BY  S_AUX.M_SCA_ORIG, S_AUX.M_TRADE_DAT)
or S.M_TRADE_NUM = ((SELECT MIN(M_TRADE_NUM) FROM SCA_FXDFWD_REP S_AUX 
where S_AUX.M_ORIGIN_ID = S.M_ORIGIN_ID
AND S_AUX.M_SCA_DESC= 'UTILIZACION'))
```

Comment: Thank you, I was using the ```OR``` condition repeating the ```select *...``` I was able to adapt your answer and I believe it's now working as expected

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are finding `max` and `min` for each `M_ORIGIN_ID`.
If this is the condition and both of your above queries are giving correct output then you may use `union all` on basis of `M_ORIGIN_ID` for `max` and for `min`.

```
select * from SCA_FXDFWD_REP S
where S.M_TRADE_NUM in  (SELECT MAX(S_AUX.M_TRADE_NUM)
                         FROM SCA_FXDFWD_REP S_AUX
                         WHERE S_AUX.M_ORIGIN_ID= S.M_ORIGIN_ID
                         AND S_AUX.M_SCA_DESC= 'ALTA'
                         GROUP BY  S_AUX.M_SCA_ORIG, S_AUX.M_TRADE_DAT)
union all
SELECT * FROM SCA_FXDFWD_REP S
WHERE M_TRADE_NUM IN ((SELECT MIN(M_TRADE_NUM) FROM SCA_FXDFWD_REP S_AUX 
where S_AUX.M_ORIGIN_ID = S.M_ORIGIN_ID
AND S_AUX.M_SCA_DESC= 'UTILIZACION'))
```